# Is there a way to select all children of one class recursively up to a different class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For instance in the code

```
<div class="ofChildClass">
  <div class="other1">
    <div class="other2">
      <div class="ofStopClass">
        <div class="other3">
          <div class="other4">Text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other5"></div>
    <div class="ofStopClass"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The elements I would want to select are marked selected, and the elements I do not want selected are marked unselected.

```
<div class="ofChildClass" unselected>
  <div class="other1" selected>
    <div class="other2" selected>
      <div class="ofStopClass" unselected>
        <div class="other3" unselected>
          <div class="other4" unselected>Text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other5" selected></div>
    <div class="ofStopClass" unselected></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make a selector, or multiple selectors that would select these elements without bruteforce.

To put the question into code is it possible to do this

```
.ofChildClass > :not(.ofStopClass),
.ofChildClass > :not(.ofStopClass) > :not(.ofStopClass),
.ofChildClass > :not(.ofStopClass) > :not(.ofStopClass) > :not(.ofStopClass),
.ofChildClass > :not(.ofStopClass) > :not(.ofStopClass) > :not(.ofStopClass) > :not(.ofStopClass)
...
```

without needing to repeat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You could add in extra class name (same for all which need to be selected). Something uunique. And then call them by using that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what kind of CSS you want to apply but this behavior can be defined using CSS variables like below:

```css
:root {
  --c:initial; /* we start by initial (nothing defined, default value)*/
}

div {
  outline:4px solid;
  outline-color:var(--c);
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
}
div::before {
  content:attr(class);
}

/* we define the color here */
.ofChildClass > * {
  --c:red;
}

/* we reset the coloration again here*/
.ofStopClass {
  --c:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="ofChildClass">
  <div class="other1">
    <div class="other2">
      <div class="ofStopClass">
        <div class="other3">
          <div class="other4">Text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other5"></div>
    <div class="ofStopClass"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you need to target divs that are marked selected only. You can do this by a code like this:

```css
div[selected]{
    color: blue;
}
div{
    color: initial;
}
```

This code target all the divs that have a selected attribute given to them. As the color property is 'inherited', I had to revert color of all the divs to initial. This is just an example, otherwise `div[selected]` will select all the marked divs.